# Grant database user folder access

Tags: mysql, privileges, mysql-error-1045

I'm trying to create a csv export of data from mysql using the following query:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM getfreepellets WHERE 1
```

And I get the following error:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user '[username]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

(removed username but it's the right one)

How would I go about granting access to this user to create a file on the server?

Edit:

I changed the first line to be my exact home path, and received the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) your user the [`FILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege:

> The `FILE` privilege gives you permission to read and write files on the server host using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` and `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statements and the `LOAD_FILE()` function.
>
> A user who has the `FILE` privilege can read any file on the server host that is either world-readable or readable by the MySQL server. (This implies the user can read any file in any database directory, because the server can access any of those files.) The `FILE` privilege also enables the user to create new files in any directory where the MySQL server has write access. As a security measure, the server will not overwrite existing files.

To grant the `FILE` privilege, log-in as root and execute:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'your_user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I'm live chatting with tech support for my host right now. I linked them your answer. Waiting...

Comment: Apparently BlueHost is unable to grant this privilege on a shared server. FYI. But, I'm going to assume you are correct and mark this answer accepted. And time to create a php export.

Comment: hookedonwinter: Thanks for accepting. I will test it out later on, to make sure that error 1045 is in fact returned when a user does not have the FILE privilege.

Comment: @hookedonwinter: Just tried it out, and in fact a user without the `FILE` privilege will receive the #1045 error. Therefore that would have solved it, if the host allowed it.